# How to compare 4 short time series in order to say if they are different?

Tags: time-series, statistical-significance, group-differences

I made a degradation test using 4 different chemical treatments as time function. How can I know if there are significative differences between the treatments  considering that they are as a time function? Or if they have the same behaviour?

```
library(ggplot2)

Days <- 0:7
Treatment1 <- c(0.000, 67.190, 78.227, 90.841, 83.972, 94.664, 97.074, 97.947)
Treatment2 <- c(0.000, 27.991, 37.136, 61.660, 72.449, 58.684, 79.962, 93.150)
Treatment3 <- c(0.000, 26.436, 29.068, 47.410, 58.281, 77.246, 79.602, 85.342)
Treatment4 <- c(0.000, 28.512, 34.734, 28.697, 47.136, 60.602, 56.394, 59.669)

DF <- data.frame(Days, Treatment1, Treatment2, Treatment3, Treatment4)

ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = DF, aes(x = Days, y = Treatment1, color = "T1")) +
  geom_point(data = DF, aes(x = Days, y = Treatment1, color = "T1")) +
  geom_line(data = DF, aes(x = Days, y = Treatment2, color = "T2")) +
  geom_point(data = DF, aes(x = Days, y = Treatment2, color = "T2")) +
  geom_line(data = DF, aes(x = Days, y = Treatment3, color = "T3")) +
  geom_point(data = DF, aes(x = Days, y = Treatment3, color = "T3")) +
  geom_line(data = DF, aes(x = Days, y = Treatment4, color = "T4")) +
  geom_point(data = DF, aes(x = Days, y = Treatment4, color = "T4")) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 0:7) +
  ylab("Degradation") +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: From the graph you posted, I would say you need more data points. Either -  the same 4 series but for a longer number of days, or multiple trials of each of the 4 treatments. As it is, it seems inconclusive.